# Writing Query with IN using EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently learning SQL and I'm currently trying to re-write a query using `IN` with `EXISTS` but nothing seems to give me the correct answer.
The question is:

For each *rating* that is the lowest (fewest stars) currently in the database, return the *reviewer name, movie title,* and *number of stars*.

Schema:

- Movie ( mID, title, year, director )
- Reviewer ( rID, name )
- Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )

My query is:

```
Select distinct rew.name, m.title, r.stars
from movie m join rating r on m.mID = r.mID 
join reviewer rew on r.rID = rew.rID
where r.stars in (Select min(stars) from rating)
```

I was trying to write is with exists by joining the subquery with the outer query. I tried all the different key's but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you first need to get the lowest rating per movie, e.g.:

```
SELECT mID, MIN(stars) AS stars
FROM rating 
GROUP BY mID;
```

And then, join it with `rating` table again, to get the reviewer id, e.g.:

```
SELECT r.rID, a.mID, a.stars
FROM rating r JOIN (
    SELECT mID, MIN(stars) AS stars
    FROM rating 
    GROUP BY mID
) a ON r.MID = a.mID and r.stars = a.stars;
```

Now, you can join the above query with Movie and Reviewer table to get the titles, e.g.:

```
SELECT m.title, re.name, b.stars
FROM movie m JOIN (
    SELECT r.rID, a.mID, a.stars
    FROM rating r JOIN (
      SELECT mID, MIN(stars) AS stars
      FROM rating 
      GROUP BY mID
    ) a ON r.MID = a.mID and r.stars = a.stars
) b
ON m.mID = b.mID
JOIN reviewer re ON re.rID = b.rID;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess using `NOT EXISTS` may do the job

```
SELECT distinct rew.name, m.title, r.stars
FROM movie m 
JOIN rating r ON m.mID = r.mID 
JOIN reviewer rew ON r.rID = rew.rID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Rating r2
    WHERE r2.stars > r.stars
)
```